# boost asynchronous (non-blocking) communication for data exchange among multi-threads

Tags: multithreading, boost

I am trying to do data-exchange communication  among boost::threads.

Different threads need to exchange data with each other. Each thread
represent a node at a network so that each thread needs to communicate
its local data with its neighbor nodes at each iteration.

Are there asynchronous (non-blocking) communication APIs in boost to do this ?

For example,

```
non_block_send(receiver_address, data_buffer, data_volume, data_tag, send_status); 

non_block_recv(sender_address, data_buffer, data_volume, data_tag, recv_status);  

if (recv_status == TRUE)   
    getData(data_buffer); 
else
    wait;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/), a library designed for asynchronous IO.

Comment: Thanks, But the data is located in memory not in disk. All threads share the same memory space. They do not need to access disk. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @Jack: No need for disk access when using Boost.Asio.